# Search level-errors with time range in log file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, logfile

I have a log file in that format:

```
2021-05-17 07:59:10.496 33821 ERROR bla bla bla

2021-05-17 08:03:10.957 33821 WARNING bla bla bla

2021-05-17 08:12:10.094 33821 ERROR bla bla bla

2021-05-17 08:40:10.592 33821 INFO bla bla bla
```

I need to count the number of level-messages (ERROR,WARNING,INFO) separately with time intervals of 4 hours.
Now, I was able to count the number of messages of each type of the entire log file, but lack the knowledge of how to count the number in time intervals every 4 hours.
Write a script in bash and sort it with awk:

```
awk '($4 ~ /INFO/)' $file | awk '{print $4}' | uniq -c | sort -r
```

similarly with error and warning

Comment: There's many things that `with time intervals of 4 hours` might mean, e.g. dumps at specific times like 4am, 8am, etc., dumps every hour on the hour of the past 4 hours counts, dumps every time a value appears of the last 4 hours data, etc. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the hour multiple of 4 before the event: `int(substr($2,1,2)/4) * 4` (e.g. for `07:59:10` this returns `4`). Then format it nicely, e.g. to print `04:00-07:59`, and then `sort` everything and `uniq -c` as you are doing already:

```
awk '($4 ~ /INFO/)' $file |
    awk '{
        x = int(substr($2,1,2)/4) * 4;
        printf "%s %02d:00-%02d:59 %s\n", $1, x, x+3, $4
    }' |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

This will print all the counts sorted by 4-hour intervals, e.g. for your example (with all lines, `cat $file` instead of `awk '($4 ~ /INFO/)' $file`) it gives:

```
      1 2021-05-17 04:00-07:59 ERROR
      1 2021-05-17 08:00-11:59 ERROR
      1 2021-05-17 08:00-11:59 INFO
      1 2021-05-17 08:00-11:59 WARNING
```

Comment: Thank you! It work, if you can - told me about parameters in substr? I wish to understand how it work.

Comment: `substr($2,1,2)` gets the substring from `$2` (the time), starting from character 1, with length 2, i.e. for `substr("07:59:10",1,2)` is `07`, which is interpreted as the number 7 when dividing by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script in bash that uses awk to count the number of level-messages (ERROR, WARNING, INFO) separately with time intervals of 4 hours:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="your_log_file.log"

# Get the current timestamp
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)

# Get the timestamp for 4 hours ago
four_hours_ago=$((current_timestamp - 14400))

# Get the number of INFO messages in the last 4 hours
info_count=$(awk -v d="$(date --date='4 hours ago' +'%Y-%m-%d %T')" '$0 > d && /INFO/ {count++} END {print count}' $file)

# Get the number of ERROR messages in the last 4 hours
error_count=$(awk -v d="$(date --date='4 hours ago' +'%Y-%m-%d %T')" '$0 > d && /ERROR/ {count++} END {print count}' $file)

# Get the number of WARNING messages in the last 4 hours
warning_count=$(awk -v d="$(date --date='4 hours ago' +'%Y-%m-%d %T')" '$0 > d && /WARNING/ {count++} END {print count}' $file)

# Print the counts
echo "INFO: $info_count"
echo "ERROR: $error_count"
echo "WARNING: $warning_count"
```